# Formatting DateTime as RFC-3339 for RSS Feed

Tags: date, datetime, rss, dart

When I print my `DateTime` with `myDate.toIso8601String();`

it prints

> 2015-11-15T11:55:32.250

Which doesn't validate with an online validator I tried. The spec says it should be of one of the following formats:

> 2002-10-02T10:00:00-05:00
>
> 2002-10-02T15:00:00Z
>
> 2002-10-02T15:00:00.05Z

I could try adding a `Z` at the end, but that seems hacky. Is there a way to print a `DateTime` in Dart so it complies to one of the following formats?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Z` is for UTC. You get it if you convert your DateTime to an UTC time with

```
new DateTime().now().toUtc().toIso8601String();
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/21e2c9d6b799f0b2bf91)

Comment: In DartPad, you have it right.  It should be:  `new DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String();`